# MongoDB compare two collections and get the 3rd collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

In my mongodb, i have few collections, i want to create a new collection by comparing the collection 1 and collection 2  using pymongo.

I want to get a third collection with, for each subject by Prof_name find matching subjects in collection2 and  the  UUID and UUID_count between a certain timestamp

```
Collection 1 :
Object id       timestamp                          Prof_Name   subjects1 
abc67478898k  ISODate("2018-01-03T09:26:37.541Z")   ABDC      "sub1, sub2, sub3"
jjjjjjjjjj    ISODate("2018-01-03T09:26:37.541Z")   XYZ       "sub2, sub4, sub8"

Collection 2 :
Object id   timestamp               UUID   subjects2            rating score
3333333    ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  7897  "sub1,sub4, sub7"     7      10
444444     ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  4532   "sub2"               4      6
777777     ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  7876  "sub1,sub2,sub3"      8      8
1111111    ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")   654   "sub1,sub3"          7      8

Collection 3 :

 objectid  Prof_name subjects_list  UUID_list           UUID-count subject_count
    12       ABDC      sub1,sub2,sub3 7897,4532,7876,654  4            3
    34       XYZ       sub2,sub4,sub8 7897,4532,7876      2            3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.6.

The below code splits the `subjects1` string into array of string values followed by [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-syntax-let-pipeline) to filter the `collection_2` documents for matching subjects and outputs the `UUID`.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) documents on `Prof_name` with `$addToSet` to keep distinct `UUID` and `subjects1` followed by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to count `UUID` and `subjects1`.

[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to write the response to new collection.

```
db.collection_1.aggregate([
{"$addFields":{"subjects1":{"$split":["$subjects1",", "]}}},
{"$unwind":"$subjects1"},
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"collection_2",
  "let":{"subjects1":"$subjects1"},
  "pipeline":[
    {"$addFields":{"subjects2":{"$split":["$subjects2",","]}}},
    {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$$subjects1","$subjects2"]}}},
    {"$project":{"UUID":1,"_id":0}}
  ],
  "as":"ref_data"}},
{"$unwind":{"path":"$ref_data","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$Prof_Name",
  "subjects_list":{"$addToSet":"$subjects1"},
  "UUID_list":{"$addToSet":"$ref_data.UUID"}}},
{"$addFields":{
  "Prof_name":"$_id",
  "UUID_count":{"$size":"$UUID_list"},
  "subject_count":{"$size":"$subjects_list"}}},
{"$project":{"_id":0}},
{"$out":"collection_3"}
])
```

Comment: i'm getting errors as pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: 'subjects'' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name

Comment: I would recommend you to run query in mongo shell first before running through python application. This will make sure you have no errors with the current query. Btw i've verified the query through 3.6 mongo shell. Add your updated python query to the post. You will need mongo server 3.6 version to run this query.Also, update to new [pymongo 3.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo) driver version.

Comment: driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.6.0" }, 
Same above query gives assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "'subjects' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name",
        "code" : 16867,
        "codeName" : "Location16867"
} : aggregate failed



changes the names of fields according my actual collection name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162445/discussion-between-rachel-and-veeram).

Comment: Found it. Its [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#user-variables) user variable name beginning with lowercase.

Comment: updated the collection names with subjects1 and subjects2. Can you please update the mongo query accordingly please

Comment: You mean the attribute name ? I see only attribute names change from subjects to subjects2. You can update answer too.

Comment: yes, since there was some confusion because of same name. I Changed it to subject1 and subject2 and updated the answer as well. Please verify once

Comment: still  I do not get the desired subject list or UUID list.UUID list and count is zero

Comment: I had a query for the same. What if subjects1 in above example is array not string. How do i modify the answer

Comment: Remove the first addFields stage if subjects1 is array.